# julia-client: can't render lazy

Tags: julia

Could somebody please explain to me what this message might mean?

I have the Julia client running in Atom, and my code works properly and it gets me the results, but for some line executions(ctrl+enter) the instant eval gives me "julia-client: can't render lazy".

It appears that the behind the scenes the code is executed, but the inline evaluations prefers not to output anything.

The lines corresponding to these messages usually should return a 2 dimensional arrays or dataframes, and in Julia usually the type and the dimensions are printed in the eval, but for some specific lines it can't render.

I could not find similar reports anywhere else.

julia version 0.5.0-rc3

Comment: What version of Julia?

Comment: julia version 0.5.0-rc3

Comment: Are you on a master branch of one of the Juno packages? Are your Atom packages up to date?

Comment: It actually did work now, how could you trace the problem?

Comment: I just know Juno really well (I'm writing the Juno docs right now). This is a problem that you saw in the past when some packages were on master and some were on release, so I just assumed that this was a package version thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with package versions being out of sync. It's you're on the Julia release (v0.5), this will be fixed with a `Pkg.update()`. In the future, this kind of question is better suited for [the Juno discussion board](http://discuss.junolab.org/)